# Error al crear componentes desde un arreglo

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Basado en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1887/c%C3%B3mo-crear-componentes-html-en-base-a-un-arreglo-de-objetos-en-jquery) intenté hacer lo mismo pero no obtengo nada.

```js
function displayResults(container, results) {

  var table = $("<div class='row tabla'  id='tabla1'>");
  $.each(results.filas, function(i, filas) {
    var tr = $("<div>");
    $.each(filas.columnas, function(i, columnas) {
      $("<div class='col' posicion='0'><p>").text(columnas.fichas.NumeroLetraSimbolo).appendTo(tr);
    });
    tr.appendTo(table);
  });
  table.appendTo(container);

}

var results = {
  "filas": [{
    "columnas": [{
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col vacio",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": [""]
      }]
    }, {
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col ",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": ["5"]
      }]
    }, {
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col ",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": ["9"]
      }]
    }, {
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col ",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": ["3"]
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "columnas": [{
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col ",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": ["8"]
      }]
    }, {
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col ",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": ["12"]
      }]
    }, {
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col ",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": ["2"]
      }]
    }, {
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col ",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": ["10"]
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "columnas": [{
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col ",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": ["11"]
      }]
    }, {
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col ",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": ["6"]
      }]
    }, {
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col ",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": ["15"]
      }]
    }, {
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col ",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": ["14"]
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "columnas": [{
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col ",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": ["1"]
      }]
    }, {
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col ",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": ["13"]
      }]
    }, {
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col ",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": ["7"]
      }]
    }, {
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col ",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": ["4"]
      }]
    }]
  }],
  "posiciones_tablero": [],
  "imagenDeFondo": []
}

displayResults($("#results"), results);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results"></div>
```

¿Qué estoy omitiendo?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que te aparece?

Comment: puedes hacer esas pruebas por tí mismo abriendo la consola de tu navegador y oprimiendo el botón ejecutar fragmento de código. A mí no me sale nada, pero tal vez no tenga configurada apropiadamente mi consola.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error está en esta línea:

```
$("<div class='col' posicion='0'><p>").text(columnas.fichas.NumeroLetraSimbolo).appendTo(tr);
```

`fichas` es un array y según la forma de tus objetos se debe escoger el primer elemento.

Es decir, debe decir `fichas[0]`

```
$("<div class='col' posicion='0'><p>").text(columnas.fichas[0].NumeroLetraSimbolo).appendTo(tr);
```

Este es el código completo

```js
function displayResults(container, results) {

  var table = $("<div class='row tabla'  id='tabla1'>");
  $.each(results.filas, function(i, filas) {
    var tr = $("<div>");
    $.each(filas.columnas, function(i, columnas) {
      $("<div class='col' posicion='0'><p>").text(columnas.fichas[0].NumeroLetraSimbolo).appendTo(tr);
    });
    tr.appendTo(table);
  });
  table.appendTo(container);

}

var results = {
  "filas": [{
    "columnas": [{
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col vacio",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": [""]
      }]
    }, {
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col ",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": ["5"]
      }]
    }, {
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col ",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": ["9"]
      }]
    }, {
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col ",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": ["3"]
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "columnas": [{
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col ",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": ["8"]
      }]
    }, {
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col ",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": ["12"]
      }]
    }, {
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col ",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": ["2"]
      }]
    }, {
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col ",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": ["10"]
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "columnas": [{
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col ",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": ["11"]
      }]
    }, {
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col ",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": ["6"]
      }]
    }, {
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col ",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": ["15"]
      }]
    }, {
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col ",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": ["14"]
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "columnas": [{
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col ",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": ["1"]
      }]
    }, {
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col ",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": ["13"]
      }]
    }, {
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col ",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": ["7"]
      }]
    }, {
      "fichas": [{
        "clase": "col ",
        "NumeroLetraSimbolo": ["4"]
      }]
    }]
  }],
  "posiciones_tablero": [],
  "imagenDeFondo": []
}

displayResults($("#results"), results);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results"></div>
```